# How can I logically OR two include? conditions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am starting learn Ruby, need some help with the include? method.

The below code works just fine:

```
x = 'ab.c'
if x.include? "." 
    puts 'hello'
else
    puts 'no'
end
```

But when I code it this way:

```
x = 'ab.c'
y = 'xyz'
if x.include? "." || y.include? "."
    puts 'hello'
else
    puts 'no'
end
```

If gives me error when I run it:

```
test.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' o
r '\n'
if x.include? "." || y.include? "."
                                 ^
test.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting end-of-input
```

Is this because the include? method cannot have handle logic operator?

Thanks

Comment: Add parentheses? `if x.include?(".") || y.include?(".")`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other answer and comment are correct, you just need to include parenthesis around your argument due to Ruby's language parsing rules, e.g.,

```
if x.include?(".") || y.include?(".")
```

You could also just structure your conditional like this, which would scale more easily as you add more arrays to search:

```
if [x, y].any? {|array| array.include? "." }
  puts 'hello'
else
  puts 'no'
end
```

See [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! `(.include?("."))` worked!  Actually `(.include?".") ` works and what I use as that makes sense to me. `x.include?(".")` still gave me errors.

Comment: `x` and `y` in the OP's code context aren't arrays, they're strings. `include?` works because String defines an `include?` method. So, technically, this answer works, but the explanation is wrong.

Comment: Don't use `(.include?("."))`. If that works, there are additional things wrong in your code.

Comment: I'm afraid my answer was written slightly confusingly: I wasn't suggesting that you wrap the `.include?(".")` in parenthesis (which is why the outer parenthesis weren't within the backticks), that was just a parenthetical example in my explanation. I've edited my answer to be more clear, and would appreciate if you could reconsider your down-vote. I agree that `.include?(".")` should be used instead of `(.include?("."))`

Answer (score 11):

It's because of Ruby parser, it can't recognize the difference between the passing an arguments and logical operators.

Just modify your code a little bit to distinguish the arguments and operator for Ruby parser.

```
if x.include?(".") || y.include?(".")
    puts 'hello'
else
    puts 'no'
end
```